# how to get size of block device if sector size of disk is 4096 bytes?

Tags: linux

**blockdev --getsz** give size in 512 bytes sector , what if sector size is 4096 bytes? if 4096 bytes sector is there, then also we can get device size from blockdev --getsz by multiplying output of (blockdev --getsz)*512?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

What is your end goal here? Do you want to know the number of `4096` byte sectors in a block device? You can simply convert the output obtained by `--getsz` to bytes by multiplying by `512` and then divide by `4096`
In Bash (assuming /dev/sdb is your block device):

`echo $(($(sudo blockdev --getsize64 /dev/sdb)*512/4096))`

Also, The [man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/blockdev.8.html) of blockdev mentions several options, one of them is `--getsize64` which will print the device size in bytes. Just simply divide this by `4096`. In Bash:

`echo $(($(sudo blockdev --getsize64 /dev/sdb)/4096))`